# Sending keystrokes to subprocess using Python's popen

Tags: python, ffmpeg, popen

I have a Python 3.6 program that is calling `ffplay` from the ffmpeg library using the `Popen` command.

I want to send `ffplay` keystrokes so I can control the playback. But nothing seems to happen. Take this example:

```
import subprocess
import time

# Array with the command in it
my_command = ("ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "examples/sounds/Fantascape_Looping.mp3")

# Open a subprocess
my_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(my_command, 
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Wait 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)

# Try to send an escape:
print("Attempt to send and 'escape' to stop the sound")
my_subprocess.stdin.write(b'\x1b')

# Wait and see what happens
print("Should no longer hear anything")
time.sleep(5)
```

I hear music for 7 seconds, rather than 2 seconds. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Sending an escape keystroke to a `ffplay` process with `-nodisp` attached will not do anything. To verify this, execute `ffplay -nodisp examples/sounds/Fantascape_Looping.mp3` and try hitting your escape key. It obviously registers, but the program does not care. So this behavior is expected.

Moreover, all keystrokes are registered by the GUI for `ffplay`, and thus nothing you pass in will matter (bar the defaults such as Control-C on Unix systems).

To solve your problem you need to diverge from trying to send keystrokes to `ffplay`. One such (fairly crude) solution would be to terminate the process directly, but this will obviously only work for stopping playback.

```
my_subprocess.terminate()  # replacing your writing to stdin
```

I could not find anything about controlling `ffplay` playback without the display except [this mailing list question](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-June/036393.html), which does not have an answer yet, it asks the following.

> Is there a means to have ffplay accept playback control from the
>   terminal rather than from the player window? Similar to how ffmeg will
>   can accept stdin input to control filters.

This leads me to believe that you might want to ask another question regarding the control of playback without display for `ffplay` here on StackOverflow (I do not have an answer for that), or use a different library.

Limited to the direct scope of your question of stopping playback, the only reasonable solution I could muster would be to terminate the process given that you have no control over the `-novid` `ffplay` process.

Comment: At least on Ubuntu 17, ``ffplay`` does work fine grabbing keystrokes with the ``-nodisp`` option. I do wonder if input is done in some manner that doesn't allow pipes to work though.

Comment: That's odd. On my system running Ubuntu 17.10 when I run `ffplay -nodisp sound.mp3` it grabs the keystrokes but does not respond to them.